Is it true that $\left\{\frac{\sigma(n)}{\varphi(n)}:\ n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\right\}=\{r\in\mathbb Q:\ r\ge1\}$?
For any positive integer $n$, let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of all positive divisors of $n$.
Clearly, $\sigma(n)\ge n\ge \varphi(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.
For any $\varepsilon>0$, we may take a prime $p>1+2/\varepsilon$ so that
$$1<\frac{\sigma(p)}{\varphi(p)}=\frac{p+1}{p-1}=1+\frac2{p-1}<1+\varepsilon.$$
Let us consider the set
$$S=\left\{\frac{\sigma(n)}{\varphi(n)}:\ n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\right\}.$$
Question. Is it true that $S=\{r\in\mathbb Q:\ r\ge1\}$?
Recently I found that all those rational numbers $a/b$ with $36\ge a\ge b\ge1$ belong to the set $S$. This led me to conjecture that $S$ indeed coincides with $\{r\in\mathbb Q:\ r\ge1\}$. For example, $41/2\in S$ since
$$25604040 = 2^3\times3\times5\times7\times11\times17\times163
\ \ \text{and}\ \ \frac{\sigma(25604040)}{\varphi(25604040)}=\frac{102021120}{4976640} =\frac{41}2.$$
Also, $41/19\in S$ since
$$121473159=3\times31\times179\times7297
\ \ \text{and}\ \ \frac{\sigma(121473159)}{\varphi(121473159)}=\frac{168145920}{77921280} =\frac{41}{19}.$$
Your comments are welcome!

The standard way to define a set is ${a\in A:\ P(a)}$, where $A$ is a set and $P(a)$ is a first-order formula in ZFC. Hence I changed ${r\ge1:\ r\in\mathbb Q}$ to ${r\in\mathbb Q:\ r\ge1}$.

You should have a strict inequality $r>1$ in the definition of $S$.

@YaakovBaruch I think he meant that $\sigma(1)=\varphi(1)=1$.

Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4449601 and https://oeis.org/A020492

This may be true even if we restrict $n$ to squarefree integers. I have verified that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{\varphi(n)}=\frac{a}{b}$ is solvable for squarefree $n$ for all $b<a\leq 100$. For example: $\frac{\sigma(n)}{\varphi(n)}=\frac{41}2$ holds for squarefree $n=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 29\cdot 163$.

Is it clear that every positive integer can be expressed as the quotient $\sigma(n)/\varphi(n)$? That might be a good start.

I think that when $p$ is prime, $a \geq 0$ we have $\sigma(p^a)/\phi(p^a) = (p^{a + 1} - 1)/(p^a(p - 1)^2)$ and it might be interesting to fix a $p$ and see what rational numbers can be obtained by varying $a$.

@JosephHarrison It is $(p^{a+1}-1)/(p^{a-1}(p-1)^2)$, limiting to $(p/(p-1))^2$. Experimentally numerator and denominator are both unbounded. This would follow from the fact that the gcd of $(p^{a+1}-1)/(p-1)$ and $p^{a-1}(p-1)$ is periodic in $a$ with period $p$ but I only have some experimental evidence for this periodicity.

@StanleyYaoXiao Up to $n=10000000$ one gets integers from $1$ to $22$, represented with the following frequencies:$$
\begin{array}{r|r}
1 & 1 \
2 & 26 \
3 & 38 \
4 & 90 \
5 & 73 \
6 & 78 \
7 & 75 \
8 & 83 \
9 & 89 \
10 & 86 \
11 & 51 \
12 & 79 \
13 & 54 \
14 & 57 \
15 & 49 \
16 & 33 \
17 & 6 \
18 & 22 \
19 & 12 \
20 & 12 \
21 & 12 \
22 & 2 \
\end{array}$$

For prime powers, $n$ up to $100000000$ (obviously it suffices to find out for them, by multiplicativity):$$\begin{array}{rrrr}\text{prime power}&\text{frequency}&\text{min}&\text{max}\
2 & 57 & 3 & 96345613 \
3 & 91 & 2 & 98380689 \
4 & 190 & 14 & 99637708 \
5 & 164 & 56 & 98691698 \
7 & 149 & 12 & 97964826 \
8 & 197 & 42 & 98389676 \
9 & 206 & 30 & 97641492 \
11 & 126 & 2580 & 99519672 \
13 & 132 & 630 & 93267360 \
16 & 86 & 20790 & 98146020 \
17 & 30 & 416640 & 99221640 \
19 & 42 & 291060 & 90638730 \
25 & 3 & 26860680 & 66186120 \
\end{array}$$

This somehow suggests that, although the moment of first occurrence seems to grow very fast, each integer is most likely represented infinitely often. (Note also that $23$ is still missing)

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე It's not quite clear to me that it suffices to get prime powers - What if $\sigma(n)/\phi(n)$ is one prime power and $\sigma(m)/\phi(m)$ is a different prime power but $n$ and $m$ share a common factor?

@WillSawin Sorry indeed I had it upside down...

Is it known that $\sigma(n)/\varphi(n)$ is an integer infinitely often?

@StanleyYaoXiao It seems that there are infinitely many $n$ with $\sigma(n)/\varphi(n)=2$. They go like$$\begin{array}{r}3\5\cdot7\5\cdot11\cdot19\7\cdot11\cdot17\cdot19\7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot29\5\cdot17\cdot19\cdot31\5\cdot13\cdot29\cdot31\5\cdot13\cdot23\cdot43\5\cdot13\cdot19\cdot71\5\cdot11\cdot23\cdot109\5\cdot13\cdot17\cdot127\7\cdot13\cdot17\cdot29\cdot31\7\cdot13\cdot17\cdot23\cdot43\7\cdot11\cdot19\cdot29\cdot41\7^3\cdot11\cdot13\cdot41\7\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot71\5^3\cdot17\cdot19\cdot79\7\cdot11\cdot17\cdot23\cdot109\\cdots\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{r}\cdots\7^2\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot191\11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot29\cdot31\11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\cdot43\\cdots\5^2\cdot13\cdot29\cdot79\cdot311\\cdots\5\cdot11^2\cdot43\cdot47\cdot229\\cdots\5^3\cdot13^3\cdot29\cdot103\\cdots\end{array}$$No idea how to characterize these...
